# PowerShell: AppActivate with PID not working

Tags: powershell

Under Windows 10, I would like to send a keypress to an existing and running windows application. The sending of the keypress works fine but the AppActivate via the PID of the windows application does not work. Here my code:

```
Function SendCommandToExistingProcess([int] $processId, [string] $processName, [string] $command)
{
  $functName = 'SendCommandToExistingProcess()' # function name for log

  Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
  Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
  [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate($processId)
  [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait($command)

  WriteLogEntry -severity $sevInfo -functName $functName `
                -entryText ("Command '" + $command + "' sent to process '" + `
                            $processName + "' with id '" + $processId)
}
```

- $processId contains the PID of the windows application to set focus to
- $command contains the keypress to send ('p')

For AppActivate I use the PID instead of the application windows title because the application title contains two special characters (similar to the copyright sign). It seems that AppActivate only works with the title (tested this successfully) but not with the PID though the AppActivate documentation shows an AppActivate overlay that acceptes a PID. I tried to set focus to the windows calculator by typing its PID as a number directly in AppActivate; did not work.

*** Update ***

The PID is obtained the following way:

```
Function SendCommandToProcess([string] $processName, [string] $command)
{
  $result    = $false                   # initialise to process does not exist
  $functName = 'SendCommandToProcess()' # function name for log

  $processId = (Get-Process -Name $processName -erroraction 'silentlycontinue').Id
  if ($processId.Count -gt 0)           # procss(es) exist(s)
  {                                     # normally just one process but could be serveral
    Foreach ($id IN $processId)
    { SendCommandToExistingProcess -processId $id -processName $processName -command $command }
                                        # send command to each of them
    $result = $true                     # command sent to specified process
  }
  else
  {
    WriteLogEntry -severity $sevWarning -functName $functName `
                  -entryText ("Process '" + $processName + "' not found (not running)")
  }

  return $result
}
```

- $processName contains the string 'Prepar3D'

When I run the above code in PowerShell with admin rights I get the following error message:

- Ausnahme beim Aufrufen von "AppActivate" mit 1 Argument(en):  "Der Prozess {0} wurde nicht gefunden."
- English: Exception when calling "AppActivate' with 1 argument(s): "The process {0} could not be found"

What is fooling me? Thanks for your help
Hannes

Comment: How do you obtain the PID? If I test with `$processId = (Get-Process -Name notepad).Id`, then AppActivate($processId) works just fine..

Comment: Hi Theo - I have added an update to my question that shows how I obtain the PID. It seems to be the same way you do it. Is there a prerequiste that makes AppActivate to work with the PID?

Comment: No, nothing special, just the `Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic` as you have it. I'm using PowerShell 5.1 on Windows 10. What is your version?

Comment: The version listed by PowerShell is 5.1.19041.610

Comment: Could there be some typo in your function `SendCommandToExistingProcess` on the `$processId` parameter perhaps? For me it is working as expected, even with multiple PIDs..

Comment: I have included both functions in my question. I can not see any typo. To test the code I use the calculator included in Windows 10. It still fails.

Comment: I think the processname of the calculator is just `calc`

Comment: `calc` is the name to start the calculator but if you look in the task manager under `Details` in the 'Name' column it says 'Calculator.exe'

Comment: That is the executable name. For notepad it is notepad.exe, where the processname is just notepad. For MS Word it is winword.

Comment: If I run the script with `notepad` it just works fine. If I use the calculator AppActivate fails. In both situation `Get-Process` locates the PID but AppActivate does not find the PID in the case of the calculator. If I used `calc` instead of `calculator` `Get-Process` does not find the calculator. Really weird. Any idea why?

Comment: `calc` runs a _Windows App_ from `WindowsApps` folder. The problem lays in fact that such apps have not set the `MainWindowHandle` property to a non-zero value. Strangely enough, `AppActivate('Calculator')` works unlike  `AppActivate($processId)`

Comment: @JosefZ You're right about Calculator nowadays is a Windows App. However, on my Dutch machine `AppActivate('Calculator')` also doesn't work. I looked at what `Get-AppXPackage -Name '*calculator*'` returns, but apparently there is nothing there that can be used for AppActivate(). I have no solution to this.. Hopefully someone can figure this out one day.

Comment: What does work is if I use the Dutch windowtitle `AppActivate('Rekenmachine')`. Been searching in the install folder you get with `(Get-AppxPackage '*calculator*').InstallLocation` for any reference to this NL windowtitle, but in vain..

Comment: Try [Inventory AppX Packages.ps1](https://github.com/skycommand/Admin-scripts/tree/master/AppX).

Comment: Thanks a lot to everybody that helps to solve my problem. But it is not the calculator that I want to get focus to. I only used the 'Calculator' to test my code. I understand that the calculator is a special case because it is Windows app. The process I want to get focus to is 'Prepar3D' (flight simulator from Lockhead Martin) and that is definitly not a Windows app. If I run my script with 'Prepar3D' in a PS Admin window, no error message is displayed but the running process 'Prepar3D' does not get focus. Instead the icon in the task bar is lit (orange). What does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem as I want to focus on an application called aces.exe. The solution that worked for me was following this guide:

https://powershell.one/powershell-internals/extending-powershell/vbscript-and-csharp#c-to-the-rescue

In this, Dr. Tobias Weltner, talks about 3 ways to focus on application windows. The one that will work for you is the Chapter: C# to the Rescue.

I used the **admin** ISE-PowerShell and copied the code from the link above. (Chapter: C# to the Rescue)

DO NOT COPY THIS CODE BUT FOLLOW THE INSTRUCTION AT THE LINKED PAGE.

This is what code I copied and used:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $code = @'
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace API
{

    public class FocusWindow
    {
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool AttachThreadInput(IntPtr idAttach, IntPtr idAttachTo, bool fAttach);


        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lpdwProcessId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

        [DllImport("user32")]
        private static extern int BringWindowToTop(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(uint uiAction, uint uiParam, IntPtr pvParam, uint fWinIni);

        private const uint SPI_GETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT = 0x2000;
        private const uint SPI_SETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT = 0x2001;
        private const int SPIF_SENDCHANGE = 0x2;

        private const int SW_HIDE = 0;
        private const int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;
        private const int SW_NORMAL = 1;
        private const int SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2;
        private const int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;
        private const int SW_MAXIMIZE = 3;
        private const int SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE = 4;
        private const int SW_SHOW = 5;
        private const int SW_MINIMIZE = 6;
        private const int SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE = 7;
        private const int SW_SHOWNA = 8;
        private const int SW_RESTORE = 9;
        private const int SW_SHOWDEFAULT = 10;
        private const int SW_MAX = 10;

        public static void Focus(IntPtr windowHandle)
        {
            IntPtr blockingThread = GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), IntPtr.Zero);
            IntPtr ownThread = GetWindowThreadProcessId(windowHandle, IntPtr.Zero);

            if (blockingThread == ownThread || blockingThread == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                SetForegroundWindow(windowHandle);
                ShowWindow(windowHandle, 3);
            }
            else
            {
                if (AttachThreadInput(ownThread, blockingThread, true))
                {
                    BringWindowToTop(windowHandle);
                    SetForegroundWindow(windowHandle);
                    ShowWindow(windowHandle, SW_MAXIMIZE);
                    AttachThreadInput(ownThread, blockingThread, false);
                }
            }

            if (GetForegroundWindow() != windowHandle)
            {
                IntPtr Timeout = IntPtr.Zero;
                SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT, 0, Timeout, 0);
                SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT, 0, IntPtr.Zero, SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
                BringWindowToTop(windowHandle);
                SetForegroundWindow(windowHandle);
                ShowWindow(windowHandle, SW_MAXIMIZE);
                SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT, 0, Timeout, SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
            }
        }
    }
}
'@

# remove -PassThru in production. It is used only to
# expose the added types:
Add-Type -PassThru -TypeDefinition $code

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                      
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                      
True     False    FocusWindow                              System.Object                                                                                                 



PS C:\Windows\system32> Add-Type -PassThru -TypeDefinition $code |
  Where-Object IsPublic |
  Select-Object -Property FullName

FullName       
--------       
API.FocusWindow



PS C:\Windows\system32> # get the main window handle for the process
# you want to switch to the foreground:

# in this example, the first instance of notepad is used
# (make sure notepad runs)
$process = Get-Process -Name aces -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
    Select-Object -First 1

$mainWindowHandle = $process.MainWindowHandle

if (!$mainWindowHandle)
{
    Write-Host "Window may be minimized, or process may not be running" -Foreground Red
}

# focus application window (and maximize it)
[API.FocusWindow]::Focus($mainWindowHandle)

PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

I also tried to use the nuget pack "PSOneApplicationWindow" that is in the first chapter in the link provided and that did not work to get focus on the aces.exe.

Answer (score 1):

I use the Main Window Handle to solve this:

Note I have a com object built named $ie

```
$app = Get-Process | ?{$_.MainWindowHandle -eq $ie.hwnd}
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate($app.Id) 
sleep -Milliseconds 50
```

So build the object, search the process by the hwnd property, pass that as the object and make that the active app. Don't forget to add the sleep to give the app a moment to pop up before moving on to the next command. It makes the call much more stable.

Comment: I had this problem. This solution works every time for me. It is a little abstract, but I build the 'AppActivate' object by calling 'Get-Process'. It will be the same app you need, it just never works right when you try to call the process by the id name. You have to actually build a new object by calling the process that is running the object that you built. I hope that helps someone out there.